# Making my computer an iPhone music dock?

Tags: macos, iphone, music, ipod, docking-station

Are there any application which lets me play the music in my iPhone through the USB cable?

It will be very convenient if I can just dock the phone (while the music is playing), and the music will come out from the computer's speakers instead of the speaker in the iPhone.

**Edit 1:**
Stock iPhone dock does have a line-out jack, thanks SidneySM for reminding me.

Now the problem is, even though I have select **Line In** as the Sound Input in Mac OSX, there is no sound coming out from the speaker. How do I make the Speaker output the Line In audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [LineIn 2.0.3](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) to enable streaming audio from iPhone dock to my Mac, now I'm able to play my iPhone Music or internet radio through my Mac's speakers!

The line out from the iPhone dock is connecting to my Mac's line in. I installed LineIn, made it run and minimized when OSX starts up and enabled **Pass Thru**.

Again thanks SidneySM for reminding me there is a Line-out in the iPhone dock!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get a dock with an audio line-out port and connect that to the line-in on your computer.

There's no way to do that in software, AFAIK.

Comment: agh...can it be done without buying another dock??

Comment: My guess is no. In Apple's eyes, that is what iTunes is for. Though I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: IIRC, the stock iPhone dock does have a line-out port. The USB cable itself does not carry audio either way, so your solution needs to involve the dock connector.

Comment: deddebme: or just connect your iPhone's headphone jack to your computer's audio in. Don't need to buy a dock.

Comment: SidneySM: actually, iPhones & iPods can play back audio over USB. For example, many iPod-compatible car stereos work that way. The problem is, when the iPod is connected to a computer it expects to be talking to iTunes.

Comment: @SidneySM Yeah there is a line out in the iphone dock! The dock sat here for a long time and I forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the output from the iPhone or iPhone dock to the input (aux) of the computer and hear the audio in the computer speakers – or the speakers connected to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way this could work is if you had itunes open to view the playlists and music on the ipod.  From there (and I only believe in manual music management mode), you can play the music located on the ipod/iphone.

Comment: Well, I want to use my Mac as a dumb speaker instead of trying to access the iPhone music from the desktop. It'll be redundant since all the iPhone musics were synced from the desktop anyway.

Comment: Yah I figured that was the ideal way you wanted it. I just offered one way that it could be done "through usb" technically.  I do understand the desire to use this setup though.  I think this concern was brought up before and I don't remember anyone having a solution besides those audio out docks/speaker sets. If your computer speakers have multiple inputs, you could get a simple audio out dock and just switch inputs on the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that this is for OSX, but for users who end up here looking for a Windows solution, Winamp with mlIpod works GREAT, it integrates your iPod/iPhone directly with the Winamp media library.

- [mlipod](http://www.mlipod.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I just connected my iphone to a computer running the newest version of Ubuntu (10.4 or something). I was instantly asked whether I wanted to open rythmbox (music program) or f-spot (some photo editor).

So I started looking for a way to do this in Windows7 and visited here on my search path.